# Assign a field mapping on the "Create copy of work item" function

Tags: tfs

When a user creates a bug on the Agile template, we have fields such as 'System Info', 'Repro Steps' and 'Acceptance Criteria'. If the bug should have been a User Story (change), we can use the 'Create Copy of Work item' link, but only the title and priority fields are migrated to the new user story.

Is there a way to define a mapping for the 'Create Copy of Work item' workflow to migrate a specific bug field to a specific user story field, and vice-versa?

Comment: Hi spikey_richie, just checking to see if the information provided was helpful.Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT I'll go ahead and raise a feature request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it's not able to achieve this. You may have to manually migrated some specific fields and values when create copy of work item'

Have raised a feature request here:

> **Customize a field mapping by using 'Create Copy of Work item' workflow**
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1145139/customize-a-field-mapping-by-using-create-copy-of.html

Kindly vote up and monitor the process. Our Product team will review it.